# Find contribution excluding certain financial types and sending email

Tags: civicontribute, email, search, receipts

I have around 30 financial types listed in CiviCRM.
I would like to find a list of contribution excluding 5 of those financial types and send an email. This is something needs doing often.

If I would not need to send email excluding certain financial types, it’s easy to use just by navigating Find Contribution and send email.  But excluding certain financial types is the only issue.

What other option do I have where I can set excluding financial types and send email? Is search-kit able to do something? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the search builder to create a smart group of contributors who have given to financial types *not in* those five types?  Then you could send an email to that group when needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It’s nearly there. How do I include a set of date range within search builder? i.e. last week, last month or last 30days etc. Otherwise all contacts is included when sending email.

Comment: I don't think relative dates are an option with the search builder; you'd need to include receive date twice, once with >= and once with <= to get your start and end dates in place.